# Switching potentiometers with shift register and transistors / darlington array in microcontroller-based music sequencer

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, potentiometer, shift-register

First some background on my project:

I am working on an electronic music sequencer for use in my modular system using an RP2040 microprocessor. There are 16 steps in the sequence. The RP2040 cycles through the 16 steps based on a frequency set using an encoder, and can move forward or backward or randomly, based on user options. Each step has a mechanical switch which is used to decide whether, when that step is reached, a 5V pulse should be emitted so that an attached drum machine will play a sound. This allows the construction of interesting rhythms. Each step has an LED indicator to show if it is active or not. Furthermore, each step has it's own potentiometer, which outputs -10V to +10V control voltage when that step is landed on. Finally, there are multiple channels, each with it's own row of potentiometers, switches and trigger and control voltage output. The microprocessor never needs to read the potentiometers; they only need to be routed to the channel's CV output.

My plan is to use a PISO shift register to sample the mechanical switches, a SIPO shift register to trigger the LEDs, and a SIPO shift register tied to transistors to 'switch' between each potentiometer.

My question is (are) simply this:

- Can I use a shift register to turn on and off transistors which
  effectively select which potentiometer will be in use? What does that circuit look like? Would analog switches be better?
- I was wondering if a Darlington array could be matched with the SIPO
  to minimize the part complexity.
- I recognize that the clockrate is very high on the shift register; Is my understanding correct that the sampling of the switches with the PISO occurs all at once, in parallel, even if the data is read in serially, or is there a delay between each input?

Any insights on this plan would be helpful. If this is the wrong venue for this question, I apologize.

Comment: I would use MOSFETs for the lower voltage drop, personally--a Darlington transistor will always have at least about 0.7 volts across it when turned on. The Si2318 from Vishay/Siliconix might be a good choice; easy to drive from logic gates, low on-resistance, available in pretty small packages but not too small to hand-solder. Might be a bit overkill, really, but they're cheap and tiny.

Comment: Have a look at MAX335 containing 8 analog switches with the needed voltage range, controlled by SPI signals. With this IC you can route different potentiometer wipers to the outputs.